# RequireJS - dependency injector or service locator

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, requirejs

Ok,

Is it appropriate/correct to be using requirejs as a dependency injector?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Beside the script loading, the main advantage of requirejs is the resolving of the dependency tree of your app. It has a bunch nice features:

- The r compiler that will resolve all dependencies and save the result as a single JavaScript file.
- You can change the path for single dependencies so you can create a mobile and a desktop version that can share some modules but the dependencies they get are different.
- You can lazy load modules later in your app